# Calculating due date using business hours and holidays in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

I was trying to build on one of the answered questions in the site regarding computing for the start date given the due date and the number of hours needed to complete the task. Was able to make it work but I am struggling right now on what to do when due dates goes beyond the business hours.  There is another example here in the site but it is for SQL Server.

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: I  have no idea how to pursue this.  I proceeded based on the answered questions here.  I will be using this to compute the due dates of an incident that is forwarded to level 3.  Current ITSM tool support only up to first level. I am actually creating a user-defined function that I will call from the ITSM tool.  What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Any answer you find in SQL Server can always be converted to Oracle -- and vice versa. Not always easily...

Anyway, working with holidays is a custom operation. Holidays are not standard from country to country, state or province to state or province, city to city, company to company or even department to department. The same for the definition of DWH.

So you will need a Calendar or Holidays table of some sort. Your company more than likely already has such a creature. If not, design your own.

The actual design could be as simple as a single date field with an entry for every holiday, be it Federal, State or special company day. A quick Google of "sql database holiday table download" turned up a lot of good candidates, some much too complex for your simple use, but even they could provide some good insights for your own design.

If, after choosing a table or designing your own, you run into trouble coding around it, give us a call.

You have our number ;)